# How to reinstall all networking drivers?

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, internet, reinstall

I'd like to do a fresh reinstall of anything related to networking, not just the network manager, back to default "just installed" settings. Reinstalling Ubuntu entirely isn't an option, I was just wondering if I could "partially reinstall" the networking parts.

The wireless card from running `lspci` is as follows:

`02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)`

Answer (score 1):

If your network configuration is somehow messed up it's better to clean its configuration files, rather than reinstall anything.

Of course you can purge packages related to network, like network-manager, remove its configfiles, then install again, but it's really dirty way of doing it.

**DANGEROUS STUFF BELOW: dreaded dragons, hot plasma, don't copypaste it**

```
mkdir ~/network_fix \
&& cd ~/network_fix \
&& dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii(\ ){1,3}network-manager" | awk '{print $2}' | while read -r pkg ; do apt download $pkg ; done \
&& sudo apt-get purge network-manager \
&& sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager
```

then reinstall it

```
cd ~/network_fix && sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

You may want to do the same with netplan.io in modern ubuntus, depending on what setup you're using.

Also you can revert changes done inside some generic configfiles like /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf, etc.

One way of doing it is to rsync anything network related from another system with same distro, f.e. installed on virtualbox, or from live CD.

However there is also whole big story about systemd in this case, but this is something beyond my nerves...

But nevertheless, you want to do some crazy things :) So I'd recommend describing what the problem is in the first place, before going wild.

Comment: I just have a plethora of issues related to connecting to wifi on wakeup and having to restart my wifi interfaces if my computer is awake for too long. This all happened after I tweaked a few things trying to fix other issues, but I do not understand what the problem is and was hoping I could just do a hard reset to fix. However, I could maintain an internet connection during reinstallation of the network manager packages, and additionally the network manager forgot none of my wifi networks.

Comment: I tried executing the same command replacing `network-manager` with `netplan` and got the following error message: 

`E: Can't find a source to download version '0.40.1~18.04.3' of 'netplan.io:amd64'`

Thank you again for the help!

Comment: I tend not to use sleep mode on my PCs at all, because all of these strange problems it generates... But anyway, this also can have something to do with ACPI. Try to disable it with grub with acpi=off